# SQL select rows case INsensitive not works my statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have Android app that sends to server pattern to find user by name. I want to be able to find rows where `VARCHAR` column is like pattern (but case INsensitive) that I send to server. Lets say we have a nickname like 'Bigboss'. The SQL statement should be able to find this row either when is passed 'Bigboss' or 'bIGBOSS' or 'biGbOsS' or 'bi' etc. Currently it works weird.

Here is my `SQL` statement:

```
SELECT * 
from users_details 
where upper(name) like '" + pattern + "%' 
   or lower(name) like '" + pattern + "%'
```

Help me please.

Comment: Either use `ILIKE` or `where upper(name) like upper('" + pattern + "%')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
  from users_details 
 where name ilike '" + pattern + "%'
```

see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-matching.html) :

> The key word ILIKE can be used instead of LIKE to make the match
> case-insensitive according to the active locale

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this.

```
SELECT * from users_details where upper(name) like '%PATTERN%'
```

If you are passing pattern dynamically then like `pattern.touppercase()`